# ImportError: The version of cryptography does not match the loaded shared object

Tags: python, cryptography, paramiko, python-cryptography

I am using Paramiko. Any idea how I can use the `Paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key()` function?
I'm interested in using a function to parse a private key and use that private key for SSHClient.

Code I wanted to run:

```py
file = './file.pem'
mypkey = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(file)
```

Result:

> ImportError: The version of cryptography does not match the loaded shared object. This can happen if you have multiple copies of cryptography installed in your Python path. Please try creating a new virtual environment to resolve this issue. Loaded python version: 2.4.2, shared object version: b'2.7'

It apears to be a problem with the lib cryptography:

```
from cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.backend import backend
```

I have python 3.7.1
I have installed Paramiko using `pip install`

Here are some infromation about the version I have used for paramiko :

```
pip show paramiko
Name: paramiko
Version: 2.6.0
Summary: SSH2 protocol library
Home-page: https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/
License: LGPL
Requires: pynacl, bcrypt, cryptography
Required-by: sshtunnel
```

Here are some infromation about the version I have used for cryptography:

```
pip show cryptography
Name: cryptography
Version: 2.7
Summary: cryptography is a package which provides cryptographic recipes and primitives to Python developers.
Home-page: https://github.com/pyca/cryptography
License: BSD or Apache License, Version 2.0
Requires: six, asn1crypto, cffi
Required-by: service-identity, pyOpenSSL, paramiko
```

I have unistalled cryptography and installed the same ver of the paramiko:

```
pip install cryptography==2.6.0
```

The same ERROR stays

Comment: I think this might be better suited [here](https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/issues/new/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is almost always caused by having multiple copies of cryptography installed simultaneously. This can happen if you've installed cryptography both with `pip` and your system's package manager. Try building a new virtualenv, installing your dependencies into that, and that should resolve the issue.

Comment: for those of us that don't know, how would we build a new virtualenv correctly?